# Dropbox and locate?

Tags: dropbox, command-line

I frequently use the `locate` command to find files on my machine, but it doesn't index the Dropbox folder.  I can't find any way to configure the folder selection.  Is there a way to include dropbox in the locate database (locatedb)?

(locate is not enabled by default on mac; you have to run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` to set it up the first time)

Answer (score 2):

Locatedb is controlled by the file `/etc/locate.rc`. You can add your dropbox path to the line starting with `SEARCHPATHS`.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it.  Any idea why the default path, `/`, is not including Dropbox?

Comment: I'm guessing because it's got a special extended attribute - you can see this by doing `ls -ld@ ~/Dropbox`.